# With uwsgi deployed Django, part css and js can get, others can not

Tags: django, uwsgi

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [

]   + static(settings.STATIC_URL,      document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

`settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

For example, `/static/picture/8.jpg` can get，but `/static/picture/9.jpg`can not.

So i `mv 9.jpg 8.jpg` and the this picture(now is `8.jpg`) still can not get？

How can i solve this？

Comment: If you are running with `DEBUG=False`, make sure you have remembered to run `./manage.py collectstatic` after updating static files.

Comment: I've run this.It still can't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably touching the wrong directory.

When you run `manage.py collectstatic` all the static files off the different apps + the ones inside the static `STATICFILES_DIRS`, go to the static root.

Make sure to put the full path of the directory you are modifying inside `STATICFILES_DIRS` and then run `python manage.py collectstatic`